# redirect with or without slash with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I use mod_rewrite to redirect the request to a PHP file :

```
RewriteRule gallery$ mod.php?m=gallery
```

everything is ok when I call the url in this format : `http://localhost/project/gallery` but when I call the `http://localhost/project/gallery/` I get the page not fount error.

What should I do to solve this problem? should I enter a duplicate line with `/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rule should be like this:

```
RewriteRule gallery/?$ mod.php?m=gallery [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you, is there any newbie document or tutorial to understand the mean of `[L,QSA,NC]` ?

Comment: Sure see this official doc: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags